# Google Maps API v3 Markers are different except icons, why?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have some simple Google Maps code which currently places three markers on the map.  The markers all appear correct in different locations with different titles and info windows however the icons which are set to be different for each all show the same.

I have looked at various other posts but none of them seem to have the same issue.  The code is as follows:

```
function codeAddressES(){
   codeAddress("BN1 3EL","Title1","Here1", "Red");
   codeAddress("BN1 4QU","Title2","Here2", "Yellow");
   codeAddress("BN1 3DL","Title3","Here3", "Blue");
}


 function codeAddress(address,title,ptContent,ptImage) {
    var imgRed = 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png'; 
    var imgBlue = 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_blue.png'; 
    var imgYellow = 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_yellow.png'; 

   switch (ptImage){
   case "Red":
       image = imgRed; 
       break;
   case "Blue":
       image = imgBlue; 
       break;
   case "Yellow":
       image = imgYellow; 
       break;
   }


  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        title: title,
        icon: image
    });


  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  var myHtml = '<strong>#' + ptContent+ '</strong><br/>' ;
  infoWindow.setContent(myHtml);
  infoWindow.open(map, marker);     

});
```

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Thanks

Gordon

Comment: This is a FAQ.  Geocoding is asynchronous.  When the callback function runs all the requests have been sent and the icon is left at the last value.  You can fix it with a function closure on the geocoder call.

Comment: You can find some examples/clues in the results of this search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[google-maps-api-3]+geocodeAddress

Comment: :-) @geocodezip many many thanks for taking the time to explain and show an example, that has fixed it and all is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[working example (with function closure)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_geocoderAndIconsA.html)

```
    function codeAddressES(){
       codeAddress("BN1 3EL","Title1","Here1", "Red");
       codeAddress("BN1 4QU","Title2","Here2", "Yellow");
       codeAddress("BN1 3DL","Title3","Here3", "Blue");
    }


function codeAddress(address,title,ptContent,ptImage) {
     var imgRed = 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png'; 
     var imgBlue = 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_blue.png'; 
     var imgYellow = 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_yellow.png'; 

    switch (ptImage){
    case "Red":
        image = imgRed; 
        break;
    case "Blue":
        image = imgBlue; 
        break;
    case "Yellow":
        image = imgYellow; 
        break;
    }
    geocodeAddress(address, title, ptContent,image); 

}

function geocodeAddress(address,title, ptContent,image) {
   geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
     map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
     bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         position: results[0].geometry.location,
         title: title,
         icon: image
     });

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
       var myHtml = '<strong>#' + ptContent+ '</strong><br/>' ;
       infoWindow.setContent(myHtml);
       infoWindow.open(map, marker);     
     });
   } else alert("Geocode failed, status: "+status);
  });
}
```